# How to run mysql command in app docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I use docker compose to run two instances

- Node backend app container (node_app)
- Mysql Container (mysql_db)

How can I connect to mysql_db and run command

`mysql -uroot -p`

directly from **node_app**

Without a correct configuration, I see error **mysql: not found** if I run it in node_app container.

I'm wondering if I can try something like SSH from node_app, then SSH to mysql_db and run mysql command. But sounds complex.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the network environment; you should be able to use the database container's Compose service name as a host name to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need install `mysql` tools into your node_app container, into your Dockerfile for instance:

```
...
RUN apt install mysql-client
```

If you just want access your database from the cli, you can probably execute `mysql` from your host machine (where you launch your docker-compose command) with this command:
`docker exec -it mysql_db mysql`

Comment: Hi, I want to access db from node_app, not from host.

Comment: So you must have mysql-client inside your container.